# How to import Java packages in Kotlin Native

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm trying to import Java package for use in Kotlin native as below;

```
/* main.kt */
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    print("Simple program")
}
```

and compile it with the below command

```
kotlinc main.kt -o main
```

I got the error message

```
main.kt:2:8: error: unresolved reference: java
import java.util.*
```

obviously I need to show kotlinc where to find java.util, how can I achieve this without using the command line? I'm on Windows 10 64 bit using Kotlin native 0.3.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You won't have access to Java packages in Kotlin Native. The whole point of this project is to run Kotlin code without a VM, so you don't have the Java Virtual Machine (or libraries) to use. You can, however, use native C libraries instead. You can find information about how this works [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/INTEROP.md).

From the [announcement post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/04/kotlinnative-tech-preview-kotlin-without-a-vm/) of the first preview of Kotlin/Native:

> Note that we do not intend to make arbitrary Kotlin/JVM programs runnable on Kotlin/Native or Kotlin/JS. It would be equivalent to implementing another JVM, which is both a lot of work and a lot of limitations for the runtime. We are going another way: providing a common language for all platforms while enabling creation of common libraries through seamless interoperability with platform code.

Comment: Thanks. If I understood your answer, and the quote, correctly is that in case you need functionality from a Java library then use JVM, and if you need native code find a third part library for native or implement yours, right?

Comment: Yes, if you want Java libraries and the Java ecosystem, you should just use the JVM. If you want to compile Kotlin to Native, you can find C libraries, Kotlin/Native libraries, or implements things for yourself.

Comment: Why isn't it possible to convert the Java code of the OpenJDK to Kotlin as well?

Comment: you can do it! but don't forget also rewrite all the java sdk apis to kotlin (io, date/time, networking etc)

Answer (score 4):

Since we can't actually add JVM-Libs to Kotlin/Native, as zsmb13 already explained, i'd like to point at GraalVM (for those who get here and do not already know about it).

https://www.graalvm.org/examples/java-kotlin-aot/

Their approach allows to use java-libs with Kotlin, because it compiles the required lib- and the JVM-classes into the native executable.