# How to use SQLite in Kotlin/Native?

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, kotlin-interop

For a multi-platform project, I consider [Kotlin/Native](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native), with the hope to have a common code base at least for business logic and saving of data.

For saving of data I would like to use a database like SQLite. However, according to [another stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852032/how-to-import-java-packages-in-kotlin-native), if I want to compile to Kotlin/Native, I cannot use any Java file. If I understand this correctly, it also means that any SQLite library I include is not allowed to import from Java.

On the search for such a library, I found two interesting database projects by Jetbrain, namely [Anko SQLite](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) and [Exposed](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed). However, when digging in their source code, at the time of this writing both import from Java (e.g. java.sql). Which probably means I cannot use them.

One idea I had was to use a [c-based sqlite](https://sqlite.org/download.html) library, since according to [mentioned thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852032/how-to-import-java-packages-in-kotlin-native), Kotlin/Native code is allowed to use c libraries. This may be possible, but I wondered if there isn't a suggested more Kotlin like way of using SQLite or another database in Kotlin/Native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to use the C SQLite library, but most of your code shouldn't work with it directly. Instead you write a wrapper which will be the more Kotlin-like way you are asking about.

I haven't seen such a wrapper done as a separate maintained project (there are *very* few libraries for Kotlin/Native yet), but Jetbrains actually has a basic one in https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinconf-spinner/tree/b1e66920ac7216d3dbc4b6b4625fb77efe23cff8/sql which you can use as base for your own.